# Calculation with two Strings, Android

Tags: java, android, string, integer

I'm trying to create a calculator for Android using Eclipse. This is my code for the function 'cal', 'cal' is executed when a button is clicked, But clicking on the button closes the application, I tried an other button with different function and it works fine. Can anyone point out the mistake that I've done?

```
      public void cal( View view ){
            EditText op = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            EditText res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

             String sn1 = n1.getText().toString();
             String sn2 = n2.getText().toString();
             String sres;
             String sop;

            int in1 = Integer.parseInt(sn1);
            int in2 = Integer.parseInt(sn2);
            int ires;


                 sop = op.getText().toString();
                     if(sop == "+"){
                                  ires = in1 + in2;
                                  sres = Integer.toString(ires);
                                  res.setText(sres);

        }
}
```

Comment: And do you have any exceptions? Your stacktrace (if any) would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post a logcat?

Comment: My guess would be that one of these `Views` are `null`. Make sure that you have named all of these correctly and that you have called `setContentView()` with the appropriate layout

Comment: you say edit Text but are refering to textview, check again your res edit text or it should be textview i guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exception in this.

I think you forgot to set the activity layout which causes your application force close.

or

Problem here

```
EditText res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Are you sure your editText name is `textView1` in your layout.

If it textView then do like this.

```
TextView res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: Oh damn...No... That is a TextView... I was previously using an EditText.. That should solve the issue..

Comment: @Rohanchrome let me know if still have problem. If its solve your problem do accept answer.

Comment: I got it to work thanks! :)
But the if construct does not work for some reason... Edittext2 value is "+" but the block of code in the if construct is not run... :/